# Is there a method to use Sendkeys with Xinput?

Tags: python, sendkeys, xinput, scancodes

Im trying to find a way send inputs to XINPUT buttons for a controller that is already plugged in. So the one python repo (vjoy/pygame) wouldn't work since it "adds" a controller.

Does anyone know if this exist?

For a similar comparison I am able to have python trigger buttons on my keyboard by using Direct X scancodes and Sendkeys but I could not find scan codes for Xinput or controllers.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is a virtual xinput controller. If so, you should check out the relatively new but excellent vgamepad library. It's a wrapper around vigem, so you can send your keys to a virtual Xbox controller.

I hope that answers your question.